# Oscillator Problem of a second order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

A free oscillator whose equation is
\begin{gather*}
x ̈ + 2x ̇  + 2x = 0
\end{gather*}
is intervened with a forcing function
\begin{gather*}
g(t) = 4 \cos(t) + 2 \sin(t)
\end{gather*}

I know the equation of the forced oscillator can be:
\begin{gather*}
x ̈ + 2x ̇  + 2x = 0,
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*}
x ̈ + 2x ̇  + 2x = 4 \cos(t) + 2 \sin(t),
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*}
x ̈ + 2x ̇  + 2x = 2 \cos(t) +  \sin(t)
\end{gather*}
but I don't have any idea why

Comment: Part (a) is basically asking you about the definition of a forced oscillator, i.e., what it means to apply a forcing function $g(t)$ to a free oscillator. If you don't know that, you should look it up in your text.

Comment: thanks the problem is that I don't know what it means to apply a forcing function () to a free oscillator

Comment: By definition, a damped oscillator subject to a forcing function $g(t)$ is described by $m\ddot{x}(t) = -kx-b\dot{x}+g(t)$. (In physical terms: the mass is subject to a restoring force, a damping force, and an external time-dependent force. Think of swinging a mass on a string back and forth with your hand: there is a natural free oscillation of the mass, and there is your own hand providing an external driving force.) In your case you have $m=1, k=2, b=2, g(t)=4\cos t+2\sin t$. So that resolves part (a).

Comment: thanks it helps me a lot